# Is there a way to talk to a Clojure REPL process from another process?

Tags: clojure, vim, read-eval-print-loop, jline

I'm wondering if I can make a Vim plugin that sends forms over to the REPL session that `lein repl` starts. Is there a way to send messages to an existing jline.ConsoleRunner process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly OT, but this is what [nrepl](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl) is for.  IIUC, vimclojure uses nrepl now for the REPLs it starts, and allows you to connect to remote Clojure processes that have started an nrepl server.  I don't think Leiningen has an nrepl plugin, though (yet).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK lein repl starts standard clojure REPL, which supports nrepl if I remember correctly since Clojure 1.3. Also, vimclojure does not start REPL by itself, it is programmer's duty - because of vim internal limitations on I/O.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [slimv vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2531) helpful.

see this SO question [Sending input to a screen window from vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318372/sending-input-to-a-screen-window-from-vim)

A general approach is to start a screen session run lein repl, then sent the vim output to the screen session.

Comment: Thanks. I use Tmux, though, and I was hoping there was a more direct way to talk to the repl process.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sattvik/lein-tarsier does more or less that ... I don't know if it's using nrepl or not, but with lein-tarsier you can have vimclojure talk via nailgun to a JVM which is also running a REPL. HTH